# VRP clarke wright Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman

So I got my coursework for my Data and Algorithms class at uni and with the problem VRP I have been given we were told to implement an algorithm to solve it, It is suggested that we use Clarke wright because it is easy to implement apparently but we are allowed to use any one we want.

Can anyone provide me good reading material on the clarke wright for beginners as I have never used it?,  I don't expect any help or anyone to write my code, Just some advice on what to read so that I can implement it.

Comment: Google is a good place to find information like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a simple implementation of the clarke&wright algorithm @ phpclasses
.org. Basically it compares cost and make pairs.